# Performance bounds for low-pass filters

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response, approximation

Precisely how does the performance of an FIR filter depend on its design criteria?

To illustrate, here is a specific question that probably does not have a convenient answer:

---

The Parks-McClellan algorithm converges to a FIR filter optimally aligned to design parameters. With it one can design a low-pass filter with minimum pass- and stop-band ripple:

> Take $\mathcal{S}_n$ to be the collection of symmetric FIR filters of order $n$:
> \begin{align}
> \mathcal{S}_n := \left\{(h_1,\dots,h_n)\in \mathbb{R}^n: h_k=h_{n-k+1} \text{ for each }k\right\}.
> \end{align}
> Write the frequency response of $h\in \mathcal{S}_n$ as $\hat{h}(\omega)=\sum_k h_ke^{-j2\pi \omega k}.$
>
> Specify a "stopband weight" $\alpha > 0$, cutoff $\omega>0$ and transition width $\varepsilon>0$. Define filter mismatch as follows:
> \begin{align}
>     \gamma_n(h; \alpha,\omega,\epsilon)\! 
> := \min_{f\in [0,\omega]} \left|1-|\hat{h}(f)|\right| + \alpha\cdot \max_{f\in[\omega+\epsilon, 2\pi]} |\hat{h}(f)|.
> \end{align}
> The Parks-McClellan algorithm with parameters $(\alpha, \omega,\varepsilon)$ converges to an $h_{best}$ which minimizes $\gamma_n(h; \alpha, \omega, \varepsilon)$ over all $\mathcal{S}^n$.

What estimating expressions depending on $(n, \alpha,\omega, \varepsilon)$ provide tight upper and lower bounds for $\min_h \gamma_n(h;\alpha, \omega,\varepsilon)$ ?

Alternatively, fixing $n,\ (\alpha,\omega, \varepsilon)$  and $\Delta > 0$, are there bounds for $\min_h \max_{f\in[\omega+\epsilon, 2\pi]} |\hat{h}(f)|$ among those $h\in \mathcal{S}_n$ that have $\min_{f\in [0,\omega]} \left|1-|\hat{h}(f)|\right| \leq \delta$

Comment: The question is pretty cryptic.  Could you expand?  Maybe refer to the source material that's sparking it?  And if the filter has outright zeros on the unit circle, then $\min_{f \in |0,\omega|} \left | \hat h (f) \right | = 0 $ -- so that's probably not what you want for a meaningful expression for $\gamma$.

Comment: No source material, unfortunately. I don't know of any strong references for this sort of thing. Added question details.

Comment: I doubt you’ll find tight bounds. Most of the examples I know of are empirical. [The Nehari (anti causal) approximant gives a lower bound, but I doubt its tight.](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/3314566_The_Nehari_Shuffle_FIRq_Filter_Design_with_Guaranteed_Error_Bounds)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there are no known tight upper and lower bounds, but there's a quite accurate empirical formula for estimating the required filter order $M$ given maximum passband and stopband deviations $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, and the width of the transition band $\Delta\omega$:

$$M=\frac{-10\log_{10}(\delta_1\delta_2)-13}{2.324\;\Delta\omega}\tag{1}$$

Formula $(1)$ can be found as Eq. $(7.117)$ in Oppenheim and Schafer's textbook *Discrete-Time Signal Processing* (3rd ed, p.570). According to the authors, this formula is due to Kaiser, who developed it based on experimental results published by Herrmann, Rabiner, and Chan.

Also Matlab's `firpmord.m` uses a similar but more complex formula to estimate the required filter order.